# How to use Box2D sensor contact to increment an integer variable?

Tags: android, box2d, libgdx

[image: Pong clone]

Firstly, thanks for your time.

How do I use Box2D Sensors on the EdgeShape(s) to determine a collision condition with the Ball, then use said condition to increment a score variable?

I am creating a Pong clone using Box2D via libGDX! I have found great examples and tutorials from iforce2d and Ray Wenderlich, however, they are written in languages and libraries that I am not familiar with at the moment. Trying to comprehend and convert the code is not working for me. If code or a link to a Java/libGDX rendition of Sensor use could be provided, I would be much obliged.

I am receiving contacts in my code, but I do not yet understand the recipe for the algorithm that would ignore contact with the paddle rectangles and arena boundary, but increment a score variable upon collision with the left or right EdgdeShape sensors.

I have scavenged the web for two weeks in an effort to find bits and pieces of useful information to hack together a solution before posting to SO, however, I am officially stumped on this one. I could use some guidance.

Answer (score 1):

i don't know how far you came with your efforts and never worked with libgdx, but the way to go is something like this:

1. `fixture.setUserData()` (could be `body`) to recognize the single bodies you have (outLeft, outRight, paddleLeft, paddleRight, ball) - this could be any useful information from Integers to the whole game object instance, what ever you need
2. set your left/right boundaries as sensor `fixture.setSensor(true)` - afaik this has to be set to not let the boundaries induct a collision
3. implement your contact listeners `endContact(Contact contact)` (or begin contact, like you want it) call and request the fixtures A and B from the contact object with `contact.getFixtureA/B()` and determine if the given collision is relevant for your needs e.g.:

-

```
public void endContact(Contact contact) {
  Fixture fixtureA = contact.getFixtureA();
  Fixture fixtureB = contact.getFixtureB();
  Object userDataA = fixtureA.getBody().getUserData();
  Object userDataB = fixtureB.getBody().getUserData();
  // check if one is ball
  if (userDataA instanceof Ball) {
    checkBallCollision(userDataB);
  } else if (userDataB instanceof Ball) {
    checkBallCollision(userDataA);
  }
}

private void checkBallCollision(Object userData) {
  if (userData instanceof outLeft) {
    //add points to right player
  } else if (userData instanceof outRight) {
    //add points to left player
  }
}
```

-4. add your ContactListener to your `World.setContactListener()`

as said, i'm not 100% sure that this will work, never used it in libgdx, just some smaller experiments with andengines box2d extension, but in fact it should be the same for both engines. here is another link handling sensors in andengine: http://www.matim-dev.com/creating-sensors.html

Comment: Thanks for your time. Your help revealed smaller answers that set me on the path to the overall solution that I have posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17901760/how-to-handle-null-pointer-exception-in-libgdxs-box2d-contactlistener/17902235#17902235.